# replace bask slash with space in python

Tags: python

I already gone through all threads but still could not solve issue

```
def process(date)
    #here how to know that I need to convert date into raw literal
    date = date.replace('\\', ' ')
process("21\3\90")
```

output

```
21 90
```

3 gets skipped

while here it works

```
print r'pictures\12\761_1.jpg'.replace("\\", " ")
```

output

```
pictures 12 761_1.jpg
```

any help to convert `21\12\1234` to `21 12 1234`

Comment: `\3` is not a `'3'`. It is a `\x03` byte. Your **input** doesn't contain a backslash there. You need to double those backslashes if you want to produce output with literal backslashes, or use a raw string literal.

Comment: Your sample where it works uses a *raw string literal*. Note the `r` in front of the quotes.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: yeah, i could not get how to use `raw string literal` in date case. Well issue does not owe downvote

Comment: @MartijnPieters Convert that to an answer

Comment: @nlper: in what date case? Your first example is already a string literal, just add the `r` in front to use the different syntax. Your last sentence lacks all context of where the data comes from or why it fails to convert.

Comment: @keyser: the question lacks context. There is obviously a confusion over what Python syntax does vs. actual string values, plus a X-Y problem where there is an unknown source for date strings (last sentence lacks context). I rather close this post as unclear.

Comment: I am getting string from user input, how do I convert into `raw string literal `

Comment: @nlper: perhaps you want to show us *how* you are getting that user input, and what the end result is (`print repr(value)` is invaluable in showing us the actual result). A raw string literal is just a *syntax*, how to express a string value without having to think about backslashes and their special meaning.

Comment: @nlper: A string literal is a string that you write into your .py file, it's not something that gets read from user input.  But from your example, I'm _guessing_ that these strings that you want to convert are actually Windows file paths. Is that correct?

Comment: okay so I am getting string parameter with value `"21\3\90"` then I dont have any clue to interprete this

Comment: @PM2Ring: not it's not file path, I am processing user inputed `date` and split date, month, year. If user input `21\3\90`  I am clue less to get all three values

Comment: **1.** Using forward slashes in dates is quite common, but using backslashes in dates is _very_ weird. **2.** If you read `pictures\12\761_1.jpg` into a Python string `s`, then `repr(s)` is `'pictures\\12\\761_1.jpg'`, and `s.replace('\\', ' ')` results in `pictures 12 761_1.jpg`, so I'm not sure what your real problem is.

Comment: @PM2Ring: in short, suppose your user inputed `"21\3\90"` and you want to separate each three value, what way will you go?

Comment: In Python 2, I'd use `s = raw_input()` `d, m, y = s.split('\\')`

Comment: @PM2Ring: it gives only two value in result , `['21\x03', '90']` : )

Comment: It would give that result of `['21\x03', '90']` if `"21\3\90"` is a literal string in your program code or in the interactive interpreter, but it **won't** do that if you read the string data in via `raw_input()` (or `input()` in Python 3) or from a file.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the backslash before the "3"
Even if the backslash is in the quotes it will NOT be escaped.
If you're programitically inserting the value in the function, then I suggest performing another .replace and replace the "\" with a "-"

That should convert the string to "21-3-90" and if you need to break it down further, you can replace the "-" to a " " as you originally intended.

```
akhter@uf8b156e44b21553641ed:~/PycharmProjects/untitled2$ python3.2
Python 3.2.3 (default, Feb 27 2014, 21:31:18) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> def process(date):
...     date = date.replace("\\", " ")
...     print(date)
... 
>>> process("21\\3\\90")
21 3 90
>>> process("13\\4\\90")
13 4 90
>>> 

akhter@uf8b156e44b21553641ed:~/PycharmProjects/untitled2$ python2.7
Python 2.7.3 (default, Dec 18 2014, 19:10:20) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> def process(date):
...     date = date.replace("\\", " ")
...     print(date)
... 
>>> process("21\\3\\90")
21 3 90
>>> 
akhter@uf8b156e44b21553641ed:~/PycharmProjects/untitled2$ python3.2
Python 3.2.3 (default, Feb 27 2014, 21:31:18) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> def process(date):
...     date = date.replace('\\', ' ')
...     print(date)
... 
>>> process("21\\3\\90")
21 3 90
>>>
```